# Why is perl complaining about a "my" when the line does not have one?

Tags: perl, variables, compiler-warnings

I have code that tries to call a function multiple times, given a list. I have a `for()` loop, and then inside the loop I call the function. However on the line with the function call, I get a strange error:

```
[Thu Aug  8 08:31:37 2013] x.cgi: "my" variable $_ masks earlier declaration in same statement at /usr/home/x/public_html/cgi-bin/x.cgi line 310.
[Thu Aug  8 08:31:37 2013] x.cgi: "my" variable $_ masks earlier declaration in same statement at /usr/home/x/public_html/cgi-bin/x.cgi line 310.
```

The error is strange because the line does not have a `my` in it at all.

Here's my code, run with perl 5.

```perl
sub cgiPrintForm {
    my $fh = shift;
    for (qw!betatest subscribe fname lname position department company address1 address2 city province postalcode country phone fax email hearofus comments!)
    {
      print $fh "\n$_: ",param($_) if defined(param($_));
    }
    print $fh
      "\nReferer: ",referer(),
      "\nRemote Host: ",remote_host(),
      "\nRemote IP: ",remote_addr(),
      "\nRemote Ident: ",remote_ident(),
      "\nUser Agent: ",user_agent(),"\n";
}
```

Obviously some of Perl's magic has gone wrong and the automatic `my` is messing me up.

Comment: use `strict` and `warnings`

Comment: Your code snippet compiles fine (even under strict). This error message often indicates that you forgot a semicolon far before the line where the error occurred. I would look immediately *before* this sub definition for possible errors.

Comment: @amon that was it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This error message often indicates that you forgot a semicolon far before the line where the error occurred. I would look immediately before this sub definition for possible errors. – [*amon*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon) [Aug 8 '13 at 14:23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127578/why-is-perl-complaining-about-a-my-when-the-line-does-not-have-one/47683672#comment26545775_18127578)

@amon's comment was correct; I had an error in another section that wasn't detected until this point (it was a missing quote or braces or something).